# Find and extract string from text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5.2 app.
In this app I parse incoming emails. In each email there is a tag connecting it to another object within the system.

**It looks like this:**

```
[Invitation_77decd78-0f77-46df-ae1c-e49f45a2a3ee]
```

Please note that both Invitation and 77decd78-0f77-46df-ae1c-e49f45a2a3ee are dynamic.
But the [] are always there, encapsulating the substring.

How can I find the above string and then extract it from a longer text (the email body)?

Comment: Please add sample data showing all variants of the UUID in square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex approach with a capture group:

```rb
s = "blah blah [Invitation_77decd78-0f77-46df-ae1c-e49f45a2a3ee] blah"
output = s.match(/\[\w*(\w{6}(?:-\w{4}){3}-\w{12})\]/)[1]
puts output  # decd78-0f77-46df-ae1c-e49f45a2a3ee
```

To also capture the portion leading up to the UUID, add another capture group:

```rb
output = s.match(/\[(\w+)_\w*(\w{6}(?:-\w{4}){3}-\w{12})\]/)
puts output[1]  # Invitation
puts output[2]  # decd78-0f77-46df-ae1c-e49f45a2a3ee
```

Comment: Thanks! I get this when I run the code: NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo, it is fixed now.

Comment: Worked perfectly! The output, is it possible to get both Invitation and 77decd78-0f77-46df-ae1c-e49f45a2a3ee?

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: Ah great! One small thing 77 is part of the ID and not Invitation. So _ is the splitter.

Comment: Then rewrite the pattern with an underscore...you said in your question that the first portion was variable.  Maybe it won't even always have an underscore separator.

Comment: Ah sorry, I want to extract [Invitation_123456]. Separator is always an underscore separator. So Invitation is part 1 and 123456 is part 2.

Comment: Answer updated again.

Comment: Strange that it is not picking up 77 just after the underscore separator

Comment: You said you only wanted the portion _before_ the underscore.  Is that correct?  I already posted something which captures everything before the UUID which you rejected.

Comment: So this is what I need. In the mail body there is [Invitation_77decd78-0f77-46df-ae1c-e49f45a2a3ee]. I need to extract this identifier from the text block and then extract the two parts, the resource type (Invitation) and the resource ID (77decd78-0f77-46df-ae1c-e49f45a2a3ee). The underscore is just to make it easier to get these parts. If the code could support one or more identifiers it would of course be cool.